# replace with sed command only the first occurence from a line number retrieved in a file

Tags: shell, sed

from this aws config file below, I want to replace the aws region only in default section:

```
[proj1]
output = json
region = aws_region

[default]
output = json
region = us-east-1

[proj2]
output = json
region = us-east-1

[proj2-frankfurt]
output = json
region = eu-central-1
```

from this command, I reach to retrieve the line number position of [default] section:

> grep -n "default" ~/.aws/config | awk -F  ":" '{print $1}'

the result is: 5 (as expected)

so, from this output (line number), I want to replace with sed the (only) first occurrence instead of "aws_region" by "eu-central-1" for example by doing something like that:

> sed -i '**7**,/aws_region/s//eu-central-1/' ~/.aws/config

where **7** is my output from the previous command

How to do this in one operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/^\[default\]/,/^$/{ s/region = .*/region = foobar/ }' file
```

Output to stdout:

```
[proj1]
output = json
region = aws_region

[default]
output = json
region = foobar

[proj2]
output = json
region = us-east-1

[proj2-frankfurt]
output = json
region = eu-central-1
```

If you want to edit your file "in place" use sed's option `-i`.

---

See: `man sed` and [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)